# Custom Decoder for struct with mulitple UInt attributes in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a generic decoder which decodes `Data`to a specific object.

The following object is given:

```
struct MyObject: Codable, Equatable {
   let firsValue: UInt8
   let secondValue: UInt16
   let thirdValue: UInt32
}
```

Now i got e.g. `Data` from `didUpdateValue` from `peripheral(_ peripheral: CBMPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBMCharacteristic, error: Error?)` and I want to transform this data to `MyObject`.

Is there a generic way available?

My current solution looks as follows:

```
internal class DataReader {
    private let data: Data
    private var cursor: Int = 0

    init(_ data: Data) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func readNext<T>() -> T {
        // Get the number of bytes occupied by the type T
        let chunkSize = MemoryLayout<T>.size
        // Get the bytes that contain next value
        let nextDataChunk = Data(data[cursor..<cursor+chunkSize])
        // Read the actual value from the data chunk
        let value = nextDataChunk.withUnsafeBytes { bufferPointer in
            bufferPointer.load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: T.self)
        }
        // Move the cursor to the next position
        cursor += chunkSize
        // Return the value that we just read
        return value
    }

struct MyObject: Codable, Equatable {
   let firsValue: UInt8
   let secondValue: UInt16
   let thirdValue: UInt32

    init?(_ data: Data) {
        let dataReader = DataReader(data)

        guard data.count == 7 else {
            // unexpected number of bytes
            return nil
        }
        firsValue         = dataReader.readNext()
        secondValue       = dataReader.readNext()
        thirdValue        = dataReader.readNext()
    }
}
```

But then for each new object I need to write an own init function. Is there more easy way available?

Comment: Your multi-byte readers are a bit dangerous. They assume that the values are in the platform's byte order. That's generally true for BLE protocols (GATT characteristics are supposed to be little-endian), and all current Apple chips are little-endian), but it's certainly not always true. I've definitely encountered big-endian ("network order") values in BLE protocols. It's absolutely not true for non-GATT protocols, so what you've written here is not a general decoding solution. Your approach also forces the object to actually store sized-integers (rather than Int), which is awkward in Swift.

Comment: There are ways to make this a bit nicer. I give some examples here: https://vimeo.com/601943234